# Can't Add a new Area in Areas folder in VS 2019 : “There was an error running the selected code generator”

Tags: asp.net-core

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iguzE.png) I wanted to Add a new Area in Areas's Folder, my project built successfully before , But I can't add a new Area and I can't Also quit my App or deny this step .
[this is How we add a new Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAY7X.png)

[and that's it the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3tjI.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error description,you build the project failed.It is caused by the error in your project code.So you need to fixed errors first in the error list and then add a new area as before you did.
[image]